# How can I assign a value to a Struct member?

Tags: struct, swift

```
struct Item {
    var name:String?
    var type:String?
    var value:Int?
    var tag:Int?
}
...
...
 let petItem = Item(name:petName!.uppercaseString, type:petType, value:0, tag:0)
 self.statusLabel.hidden = false
 if addItem(petItem) {
    self.statusLabel.text = petName! + " successfully added."
    self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
 } else {
    self.statusLabel.text = "Sorry, Pet couldn't be added."
 }
...
...
func addItem(petItem:Item) -> Bool {
    if treeIsFull() {
        println("Tree is full\n")
    } else {
        petItem.name = "turkey" <--- *** error ***
...
```

I can't assign values to any members of a struct.  
I get the following error:

**Error:** Cannot assign to 'name' to 'petItem'.

Is there a remedy or must I assign ALL values during *instance creation*?

Answer (score 9):

The reason you're seeing that error is that `petItem` is immutable (you can't change it) inside `addItem`. If you want to change the instance you pass in, you'll need to declare the function this way:

```
func addItem(var petItem:Item) -> Bool { ...
```

Unfortunately, now you have another error, since the `petItem` variable you created initally with `let` is immutable. So change that to `var` and off you go:

```
var petItem = Item(name:petName!.uppercaseString, type:petType, value:0, tag:0)
```

So now you can run your code, and you might realize that the `name` you set in `addItem()` isn't making it out to your `petItem` variable. What happened? In Swift `struct` instances are passed to functions by value, so nothing that happens to a parameter in the function affects the original variable, unless the parameter is declared as `inout`. So let's do that:

```
func addItem(inout petItem:Item) -> Bool { ...
```

and you'll need to change your call to show that you know this parameter can be modified:

```
if addItem(&petItem) { ...
```